# How to vertically center a list in a nav-bar

Tags: html, css

For example in: http://codepen.io/SimpleRoger/pen/OmRKNq

I want to center the: Projects, Why Us and Contact vertically; rather then being right up at the top.

```css
header {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #55d6aa;
}

.navcontainer {
  width: 97%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #AAAAAA;
  position: relative;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  /*background: #FFFF22;*/
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  /*yellow*/
}

.title {
  /*background: #ffff33;
  /*white*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  /*background:#00ff00;  */
  /*green*/
}

nav li {
  /*background: #AE1234;
  /*red*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #123;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: upper-case;
  font-weight: 800;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vertigo Web Design</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navcontainer clearfix">
      <h1 class="title">Vertigo Web Design</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Why Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add this `nav li { padding: 8px 0;}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: If you don't want to use display:table property then You can use **nav li a { line-height : (nav-height value)px; }** .

Comment: A hey guys i added bootstrap and now it looks funny? Anyone know why???

Comment: Before both things were on the same line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `display: table;` to `.navcontainer` and added

```
nav,.title {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
header {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #55d6aa;
}

.navcontainer {
  width: 97%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #AAAAAA;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  /*background: #FFFF22;*/
  /*yellow*/
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.title {
  /*background: #ffff33;
  /*white*/
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  /*background:#00ff00;  */
  /*green*/
}

nav li {
  /*background: #AE1234;
  /*red*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #123;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: upper-case;
  font-weight: 800;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vertigo Web Design</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navcontainer clearfix">
      <h1 class="title">Vertigo Web Design</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Why Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Edited. Pls check now.

Comment: Hey mate thanks but don't some people say not to use tables?